# What is the appropriate way to ask about filling in documents?

Tags: grammaticality

My uncle sent me documents which were to be filled in by me.

Now I am confused what to write in an email telling him "I filled these documents."

> Are these documents filled fine?

> Have these documents filled fine?

> Did I fill these documents fine?

Can all three be used? Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Neither "filled" nor "fine" sound good to me in this context. I suggest *"Did I **complete** these documents **correctly/properly**?"* (or, more informally, ***okay***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In India (and other regions, I assume), "filled" is the common term for documents or forms that we would consider to have been "filled out" or "completed". It has always sounded strange to me, but I would have to describe it as accurate to a regional parlance... not that I have any idea what that means in terms of how to treat this question on this site.

Comment: @Tyler: I think OP's use of "document" here must be regional - it certainly threw me a bit. And 422 instances of [filled out the document](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22filled+out+the+document%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) compared to 108,000 instances of [filled out the **form**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22filled+out+the+form%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) suggests it's not at all common. To my mind, *documents* aren't something you "fill in" - at most you might *sign* them (by way of proving that you have read and agreed/verified all the pre-printed details).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yeah, that one I'm not sure about. To my mind, "document" is technically correct (all forms are documents, though not all documents are forms), but I agree that it is an odd-sounding use and I don't think there's any problem recommending against it.

Comment: @Tyler: Noting that OP used "filled in" quite naturally and correctly in his first sentence, I think it was just carelessness/writing in an unfamiliar language that caused the preposition to get lost in each of the next four sentences. So answers focussing on the UK/US *in/out* split are probably a bit irrelevant. OP really needs to know things like the fact that "fine" is very "unidiomatic" here, and that his second example should be something more like *"Have these forms **been** filled in properly?"*, or *"**Are** these forms filled out correctly?"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I think you're right. Do you think we need another answer?

Comment: This isn't another answer, but I would add that fine simply means "quite well" rather than "correctly".  As such it isn't quite the correct word here.

Answer (score 5):

The typical phrase is *filled out*:

> I filled out the documents you sent me.

As for *fine* I would chose a word similar to *correct*:

> Are these documents filled out correctly?

Also, as some of the comments have pointed out, people more commonly use "forms" when referring to these sorts of documents.

Comment: Which regional form/dialect of English are you referring to when stating "The typical phrase is filled out."? In BrE, the typical phrase is "filled *in*".

Comment: @TrevorD In AmE we say "Fill in the blank" but "Filled out the forms/paperwork." Interesting where BrE and AmE overlap, and where they don't!

Comment: @TrevorDm, WendiKidd: There is a bit of a UK/US split over *filled in/out*, but none of us normally do this at all with *documents* (it's nearly always *forms*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: AmE uses the phrase "fill out these documents" quite frequently. *Forms* are merely one kind of document.

Comment: @ MrHen: You personally may be quite used to *filling out **documents***. But as the link in my comment to the question makes clear, it's not at all common by comparison with *filling out **forms***. To most people, a *document* is normally a piece of paper written/printed by *officialdom*, given to the "holder" so he can prove that whatever it says is recognised/accepted by the authorities. *Forms*, on the other hand, are those pieces of paper used to transfer information from the "prospective holder" to the authorities in order to actually produce the final "document/certificate".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I just reused documents because that is what the original question used. There isn't anything wrong with using the phrase "filled out these documents."

Comment: @ MrHen: I'm not saying there's anything "wrong" with using *documents* in this context. Just that relatively speaking the extent to which it's avoided by *all* Anglophones is far greater than the extent to which Brits avoid *filled out*, or Americans avoid *filled **in***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: American's don't avoid the phrase. Why would they?

Comment: @ MrHen: I'm guessing because *on average* they have the same notions as me about the difference between a document and a form. Brits avoid it even more (there are only 6 instances of BrE [filled **in** the document](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22filled+in+the+document%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books). But per my original link, 422 *documents* compared to 108,000 *forms* could reasonably be characterised as "avoidance". That's not to mention 260,000 "BrE" [filled **in** the form](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22filled+in+the+form%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: Why are you confusing search results with the concept of *avoidance*?